What does `OP_CHECKSEPARATESIG` refer to?
I was reading about potential OP_CAT applications and read about OP_CHECKSEPARATESIG. This seems to refer to some shorthand, as I am not aware of an opcode by that designation. What is OP_CHECKSEPARATESIG?

OP_CHECKSEPARATESIG has not been formally proposed for bitcoin, but it would amount to an opcode that consumes the parts of a bitcoin signature (r and s and sighash mode) separately, rather than from a single argument.
This separation of r and s allows the r value to be fixed by a bitcoin locking script, which ensures that only one signature for a specific script branch can be produced by the signer without revealing their secret key.
Having a branch that can only be signed once enables the construction of spending bonds which could enable specialized protocols, including zero-conf-safe wallets and a subset of multiparty channel factories.
If OP_CAT is enabled for bitcoin, there is no need for OP_CHECKSEPARATESIG as OP_CAT can be used to build a combined signature from the separate parts without a specialized opcode.
